# Find the orbit and the stabilizer of the group $G\leq S_8$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ be the subgroup of $S_8$ generated by $(123)(45)(78)$, then $G$ acts on $X=\{1,2,3,...,8\}$. Find the orbit and the stabilizer of every element.

---

I want to make sure I understand it, I am gonna find the orbit-$τ(x)$ and the stabilizer-$st(x)$ of the element $2\in X$

first consider $σ_1=(123),σ_2=(45),σ_3=(78)$

Then $τ(3)=\{σ_1σ_2σ_3, σ_1^2σ_2σ_3,e_1σ_2σ_3,σ_1e_2σ_3,σ_1^2e_2e_3,σ_1^2σ_2e_3\}$ ? (where $e_i$ is the identity of that cycle)

and $st(2)=\{e_1σ_2σ_3,e_1e_2σ_3,e_1e_2e_3,e_1σ_2e_3\}$ ?

Comment: But the orbit should be a subset of $X$.

Comment: @DerekHolt then the orbit is $\{3,1,2\}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look again at the definition of an orbit of an element. When a group $G$ is acting on a set $X$, the orbit of an element $x\in X$ is, loosely speaking, the set of elements of the set $X$ you can reach by acting on $x$ with something in the group. Formally, $Orb(x)=\{g\cdot x|g\in G,x\in X\}.$

In your case, since all any element of $G$ can do is send $2$ somewhere in $\{1,2,3\},$ that is the orbit of $2$.

Regarding the stabilizers: first the definition. The stabilizer of an element $x\in X$ is the set of elements of the group that send $x$ to itself. Formally, $Stab(x)=\{g\in G|g.x=x\}$.

So to find $Stab(2)$, we're interested in which elements of the group $G$ send $2$ to itself. Just what are the elements of $G$ anyway? Well, $G$ is the subgroup of $S_8$ generated by the permutation $g=(123)(45)(78)$. That is, the elements of $G$ are the powers of this permutation. For instance,
$$g^2=(132),g^3=(45)(78),g^4=(123),\dots$$

As it turns out, there's only 6 different elements in $G$. See if you can prove this *without listing them!*

In particular, what you wrote as $e_1\sigma_2 e_3$ (in my notation the permutation (45)) is **not** in $G$. In fact, knowing $G$ and $Orb(2)$, we can immediately deduce the number of elements in the $Stab(2)$ using the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem: $$|Stab(2)|=\frac{|G|}{|Orb(2)|}=\frac{6}{3}=2.$$

So if you can find two elements in $G$ which fix $2\in X,$ you'll know what the stabilizer $Stab(2)$ is.

This might seem like a lot of work to do for each element in $X$, but once you know what the elements of $G$ are, what the orbits of the action are (recall they partition X) and hence what the size of each stabilizer must be, it's actually really straightforward to do.

Comment: Thank you soo much !